# How can I access my android phone's storage from another device using LAN

Tags: storage, lan

How can I access my android phone's storage from another device such as android or PC using LAN?

With ES File Explorer, I used remote manager, but there I am to download files then I am able to use them. 
But I want such a system, by which I can stream my audio, video from my android device's storage without downloading through LAN network.

Comment: Go for one of SSHFS, CIFS, NFS, ADBFS etc.

Comment: Install an [DLNA server](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/multimedia_dlna?lang=en)